# `this`-context in constructor unclear

Tags: javascript, constructor

What I want is an object with a value (clazz) and a function(test), where the function delivers the value.

https://jsfiddle.net/pzy9dm9x/2/

```
var Clazz = function(object) {
     for(o in object) {
     this[o] = object[o];
     }
  return this;
}
var Construct = Clazz({
                 clazz : "xyz",
                 test  : function () {
                           console.log(this.clazz);
                         }
                 });
var a = new Construct();
console.log(a);
a.test();
```

I want: `xyz`

I get: `TypeError: Construct is not a constructor`

Answer (score 1):

Your `Clazz` function does not return a constructor function. I think you actually want something like

```
function Construct() {
    Clazz.call(this, {
        clazz : "xyz",
        test  : function () {
            console.log(this.clazz);
       }
    });
}
```